# Menu Item - Single Article for my Component NOT WORKING

Tags: component, menu-item

I'm developing a simple component for eg. "Article Files" component and its models are "Article" and "Article Files".

When i'm creating a menu item for my component for frontend and selecting a Single Article I can't select a specific item instead the component URL is on the textbox. see the attached image. 
How I can fix this? I want something like the "Articles" built in Joomla whereis you can select a specific article and display it in the frontend.
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a field named **modal_article** available in the com_content component.

You can use that field in your xml file for article selection.

Code for this field is available at  `administrator/components/com_content/models/fields`

You can take reference from single article menu xml for the usage.

Refer file at  `Joomla-root/components/com_content/views/article/tmpl/default.xml`

Comment: I'm sorry but there is no default.xml file in the `components/com_content/views/article/tmpl/`

Comment: this file is located at Joomla-root/component/com_content/views/article/tmpl/  

not in administrator section

Comment: I should have added complete path..answer edited :)